# Unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Tags: r

I'm trying to select columns from a data frame by the following code.

```
library(dplyr)
dv %>% select(LGA)
select(dv, LGA)
```

Both of them will fail with the error

> Unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

But the following code will be fine.

```
dplyr::select(dv, LGA)
```

Is this a function confliction in packages?

All libraries imported are as the following.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(geojsonio)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(geojson)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(scales)
```

I'm new to R, so super confused how you guys deal with problems like this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's a great package that helps with package conflicts called [conflicted](https://github.com/r-lib/conflicted).

If you type `search()` into your console, you'll see an ordered vector of packages called the "search list". When you call `select`, R searches through this "search path" and matches the first function called `select`. When you call `dplyr::select` you're calling it **directly** from the namespace `dplyr`, so the function works as expected.

Here's an example using `conflicted`. We'll load up raster and dplyr, which both have a `select` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(raster)
library(conflicted)

d <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
```

Now when we call `select`, we're prompted with the exact conflict:

```
> select(d, a)
Error: [conflicted] `select` found in 2 packages.
Either pick the one you want with `::` 
* raster::select
* dplyr::select
Or declare a preference with `conflict_prefer()`
* conflict_prefer("select", "raster")
* conflict_prefer("select", "dplyr")
```

Comment: This was exactly my issue: having both `raster` and `dplyr` libraries loaded

Answer (score 9):

This function `dplyr::select` solved my problem.