# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"spec_tbl_df"’

Tags: r, csv, dbf

I am having this error code appear on in my project.

the strange thing is, the piece of code I am using was working perfectly earlier today. However, since I installed an update for R I am now getting this message when running it.

```
df1 <- df %>% select(Month, Longitude, Latitude, Type)

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"spec_tbl_df"’
```

The code was used simply to create a new data frame with only the selected columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the new version of `R` you have ? `version` command can be run

Comment: Hi there linog, Im now running version 4.0.0. I updated it because R markdown was not running. Now Rmarkdown works but my code does not.

Comment: Ok this can come from the `R` `4.0.0` update. Or maybe it comes from [that](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/951). Did you try writing `dplyr::select` rather than `select` ?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you submit an answer I will accept it linog

Comment: Cool ! I edited my previous answer to put this solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411834/unable-to-find-an-inherited-method-for-function-select-for-signature-data-fr)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A new version of `R` has recently been released: `4.0.0`.

There has been some major changes, [see here for a list](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html). The documentation says that this might have broken some methods that were based on `R` 3.6.* behavior. Maybe the method for the class `spec_tbl_df` was relying on something that changed.

That's a clue more than a definitive answer, maybe some users will give you a better one

## Update

Given the *issue* [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/951), it looks like there exists a conflict between the base `R` `select` method and `dplyr::select` method for objects of class `spec_tbl_df`. In that case, the easiest solution is to ensure you use `dplyr` namespace by using the `dplyr::select` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I have forgot add dbDriver("PostgreSQL") in my case. This will help  maybe )

```
db_con = dbConnect(
    **dbDriver("PostgreSQL")**, 
    user='****',
    password='****',
    dbname='****',
    host='****',
    port='****'
  )
```