# R filtering a dataframe using a vector

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe which has 9 columns, I want to filter the rows based on another list.
The list items are in the 9th column of the dataframe but there are other information in the same column as well.

Dataframe:

```
ST4.03ch01  Cufflinks   mRNA    152322  153489  .   -   .   ID=PGSC0003DMT400039136;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400015133;Source_id=RNASEQ26.809.0;Mapping_depth=16.192011;Class=4;name=Defensin
ST4.03ch01  GLEAN   mRNA    160499  160663  .   -   .   ID=PGSC0003DMT400039133;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400015132;Source_id=PGSC0003DMG000019750;Class=2;name=Defensin J1-2
ST4.03ch01  Cufflinks   mRNA    160379  161885  .   -   .   ID=PGSC0003DMT400039134;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400015132;Source_id=RNASEQ26.803.0;Mapping_depth=35.840147;Class=2;name=Defensin J1-2
ST4.03ch01  Cufflinks   mRNA    225084  229469  .   +   .   ID=PGSC0003DMT400058594;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400022764;Source_id=RNASEQ39.8869.0;Mapping_depth=158.359878;Class=1;name=Glutamate decarboxylase isoform3
ST4.03ch01  Cufflinks   mRNA    248940  249501  .   -   .   ID=PGSC0003DMT400058700;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400022799;Source_id=RNASEQ39.8875.0;Mapping_depth=16.138790;Class=5;name=Gene of unknown function
ST4.03ch09  GLEAN   mRNA    50581315    50583516    .   -   .   ID=PGSC0003DMT400009752;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400003817;Source_id=PGSC0003DMG000004746;Class=2;name=RNA-directed DNA polymerase (Reverse transcriptase); Ribonuclease H
ST4.03ch05  Cufflinks   mRNA    1469122 1469329 .   -   .   ID=PGSC0003DMT400064680;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400025123;Source_id=RNASEQ55.4892.0;Mapping_depth=2.218355;Class=2;name=Class S F-box protein
```

vector:

```
 [1] "PGSC0003DMT400035774"                     "PGSC0003DMT400086293"                 "PGSC0003DMT400086672" "PGSC0003DMT400095645" "PGSC0003DMT400091693" "PGSC0003DMT400080908"
 [7] "PGSC0003DMT400087868" "PGSC0003DMT400086807" "PGSC0003DMT400085319" "PGSC0003DMT400088916" "PGSC0003DMT400076675" "PGSC0003DMT400092517"
[13] "PGSC0003DMT400009752" "PGSC0003DMT400084819" "PGSC0003DMT400092699" "PGSC0003DMT400085283" "PGSC0003DMT400086058" "PGSC0003DMT400064680"
```

The list items matches with the ID=........ part.
My ideal result would be having the `name=...`. the equivalent of the list items.

Ideal output:

```
PGSC0003DMT400009752    RNA-directed DNA polymerase (Reverse transcriptase); Ribonuclease H
PGSC0003DMT400064680    Class S F-box protein
```

Any ideas?

Thank you,
I

Comment: I posted a solution below based on the data you showed.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently working on it

Comment: Yes, of course, I will accept it as the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the text after `'ID'` and `'name'` into separate columns and then keep only those rows that are present in the vector.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::extract(v9, c('ID', 'details'), 'ID=(\\w+);.*name=(.*)') %>%
  filter(ID %in% vector) %>%
  select(ID, details) -> result

result
#                    ID                                                             details
#1 PGSC0003DMT400009752 RNA-directed DNA polymerase (Reverse transcriptase); Ribonuclease H
#2 PGSC0003DMT400064680                                               Class S F-box protein
```

Comment: This worked for me as well! I just had to use `dplyr::select` instead of `select `. Related post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61428630/14670139)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `str_detect` and `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   filter(str_detect(v9, str_c("\\b(", str_c(vec1, collapse="|"), 
      ")\\b"))) %>% 
   transmute(ID = str_extract(v9, "(?<=ID\\=)\\w+"), 
       details = str_extract(v9, "(?<=name\\=).*"))
```

-output

```
#          ID                                                             details
#1 PGSC0003DMT400009752 RNA-directed DNA polymerase (Reverse transcriptase); Ribonuclease H
#2 PGSC0003DMT400064680                                               Class S F-box protein
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("ST4.03ch01", "ST4.03ch01", "ST4.03ch01", 
"ST4.03ch01", "ST4.03ch01", "ST4.03ch09", "ST4.03ch05"), v2 = c("Cufflinks", 
"GLEAN", "Cufflinks", "Cufflinks", "Cufflinks", "GLEAN", "Cufflinks"
), v3 = c("mRNA", "mRNA", "mRNA", "mRNA", "mRNA", "mRNA", "mRNA"
), v4 = c(152322L, 160499L, 160379L, 225084L, 248940L, 50581315L, 
1469122L), v5 = c(153489L, 160663L, 161885L, 229469L, 249501L, 
50583516L, 1469329L), v6 = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."
), v7 = c("-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-"), v8 = c(".", ".", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "."), v9 = c("ID=PGSC0003DMT400039136;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400015133;Source_id=RNASEQ26.809.0;Mapping_depth=16.192011;Class=4;name=Defensin", 
"ID=PGSC0003DMT400039133;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400015132;Source_id=PGSC0003DMG000019750;Class=2;name=Defensin J1-2", 
"ID=PGSC0003DMT400039134;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400015132;Source_id=RNASEQ26.803.0;Mapping_depth=35.840147;Class=2;name=Defensin J1-2", 
"ID=PGSC0003DMT400058594;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400022764;Source_id=RNASEQ39.8869.0;Mapping_depth=158.359878;Class=1;name=Glutamate decarboxylase isoform3", 
"ID=PGSC0003DMT400058700;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400022799;Source_id=RNASEQ39.8875.0;Mapping_depth=16.138790;Class=5;name=Gene of unknown function", 
"ID=PGSC0003DMT400009752;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400003817;Source_id=PGSC0003DMG000004746;Class=2;name=RNA-directed DNA polymerase (Reverse transcriptase); Ribonuclease H", 
"ID=PGSC0003DMT400064680;Parent=PGSC0003DMG400025123;Source_id=RNASEQ55.4892.0;Mapping_depth=2.218355;Class=2;name=Class S F-box protein"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

vec1 <- c("PGSC0003DMT400009752", "PGSC0003DMT400009752", "PGSC0003DMT400084819", 
"PGSC0003DMT400092699", "PGSC0003DMT400085283", "PGSC0003DMT400086058", 
"PGSC0003DMT400064680")
```

Comment: I'm getting `[1] ID      details
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)` as result I'm working on it sorry it's taking a bit long.

Comment: @Ibozanova I showed a reproducible example with the data I used and the vector

Comment: I actually just got it! Thank you for your help!